# What does the output of gen_coeffs.gen_two_diode in PVMismatch mean?

Tags: pvlib

I do not understand the Output of gen_coeffs.gen_two_diode, which is:

```
fjac: array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
    ... nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
         fun: array([-5.00391537e-02, -5.32664899e-02, -5.71223793e-02, -  5.97740265e-02,-6.18808152e-02, -6.36665900e-02...-1.94677609e-07,
    -2.92041963e-07, -3.89423353e-07, -4.86821782e-07, -5.35527386e-07])
        ipvt: array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
    message: 'The cosine of the angle between func(x) and any column of the\n  Jacobian is at most 0.000000 in absolute value'
      nfev: 1
      njev: 1
      qtf: array([nan, nan, nan, nan])
      status: 4
    success: True
    x: array([-24.51750581, -13.41004545,   0.06324555,   3.16227766])
```

Can I find the values which I need (Isat1, Isat2, Rs and Rs) in this output ?  or  after using the gen_coeffs.gen_two_diode where can I find the parameters needed for the 2 diode model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is the typical output of a Scipy method for the solver. Values I am looking for are in the x array
[-24.51750581, -13.41004545,   0.06324555,   3.16227766]. But a bit encrypted:

The Result of the saturation currents are given as the exponent of the e function and the Shunt and Series resistance are expresed as the RMS.

```
isat1 = np.exp(sol.x[0])
isat2 = np.exp(sol.x[1])
rs = sol.x[2] ** 2.0
rsh = sol.x[3] ** 2.0
```